# "Symbol 'grub_efi_secure_boot' not found" after disk replacement on boot (CentOS 7.5, RAID1)

Tags: centos7, raid1, nvme

Recently I had to replace a faulty HD at a Centos 7.5 server with RAID1 (2 x Samsung NVMe disks)

After disk replacement, server booted using the other drive,  I copied the same partitions at the new disk with fsdisk, added partitions to RAID, and after RAID got synched, I installed GRUB at the new HD with:

```
grub2-install /dev/nvme1n1
```

in order to make it bootable (so if the other disk fail, server will still be able to boot).

After I rebooted the server, GRUB menu appeared, but after selecting any kernel, the server stops booting with error:

```
symbol 'grub_efi_secure_boot' not found
```

I managed to restart the server after changing the boot sequence in BIOS, selecting the old drive first.

How can I make the new disk bootable? Please note that server has BIOS, not UEFI and I got it with a pre-installed image.

## lsblk

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1     259:0    0   477G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:2    0    32G  0 part
│ └─md0       9:0    0    32G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p2 259:3    0   512M  0 part
│ └─md1       9:1    0 511.4M  0 raid1 /boot
└─nvme0n1p3 259:4    0 444.4G  0 part
  └─md2       9:2    0 444.3G  0 raid1 /
nvme1n1     259:1    0   477G  0 disk
├─nvme1n1p1 259:5    0    32G  0 part
│ └─md0       9:0    0    32G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─nvme1n1p2 259:6    0   512M  0 part
│ └─md1       9:1    0 511.4M  0 raid1 /boot
└─nvme1n1p3 259:7    0 444.4G  0 part
  └─md2       9:2    0 444.3G  0 raid1 /
```

## cat /proc/mdstat

```
Personalities : [raid1]
md1 : active raid1 nvme1n1p2[2] nvme0n1p2[0]
      523712 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md2 : active raid1 nvme1n1p3[2] nvme0n1p3[0]
      465895744 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 2/4 pages [8KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active raid1 nvme0n1p1[0] nvme1n1p1[2]
      33521664 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

Comment: Have you tried disabling secure boot in the BIOS? Did it change anything?

Comment: Secure boot option is available only to UEFI systems, not classical BIOS

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix boot issue by also re-building initramfs: after I rebuilt the RAID array and installed grub2 at new disk, I run

```
dracut -f
```

It is suggested to keep a backup of your current initramfs img file first. You can rebuild initramfs img files for any available kernel in your system. See more [here](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-6-how-to-rebuild-initial-ramdisk-image/)

I do not know why this was necessary, since the new disk was exactly the same as the old one (manufacturer/model), so new drivers stored in initramfs should not be needed.